# MySQLSyntaxErrorException with table name "condition"

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table called `condition`. I need to keep it with that name, but when I execute the command

```
Query qb = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Condition c ")
```

I get this exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition' at line 1
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2683)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2144)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:931)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:607)
```

I know that MySQL has a command called condition and that's why this command throws me an exception.

Is there a form to keep my table named as condition, and that would allow me to execute the following command?

```
Query qb = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Condition c ")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because **condition** is a [*reserved keyword* of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Try this:

```
Query qb = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM `Condition` c ")
```

Check *[Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)* for more details.

I hope it may helps you!

Answer (score 4):

`CONDITION` is a reserved keyword. It must be escaped using [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming):

```
SELECT c FROM `Condition` c
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have a chance to alter the identifier, change the table name which is not present on the reserved keyword list. This will avoid you from future headaches.

Comment: Can you help me understand how [tag:mysql-error-1064] adds value to this question?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO 1064 is the code for syntax in mysql right? I know that you know that. What else is your question? Query Tag? Select Tag? just ask.

Comment: Actually, I don't; but have seen it. Regardless, it does not add value to the question. Take a look at [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99072/should-adding-redundant-but-related-tags-be-encouraged-or-discouraged)